# Convert a php code into javascript code

Tags: php, javascript

I need to display data from a table and each entry has a parent, my php code looks like this:

```
function makeArbo($array, $currentParent = 0, $currLevel = 0, $prevLevel = -1, &$result = '')
        {
            if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0)
            {
                foreach ($array as $item)
                {
                    if ($currentParent == $item['idParent'])
                    {                      
                        if ($currLevel > $prevLevel)
                            $result .= '<ul>';

                        if ($currLevel == $prevLevel)
                            $result .= '</li>';

                        $result .= '<li>'.$item['name'].'</li>';

                        if ($currLevel > $prevLevel)
                            $prevLevel = $currLevel;

                        $currLevel++;

                        makeArbo($array, $item['id'], $currLevel, $prevLevel, $result);

                        $currLevel--;
                    }  
                }

                if ($currLevel == $prevLevel)
                    $result .=  '</li></ul>';

                return $result;
            }
        }

        echo makeArbo($array);
        ?>
}
```

My table look like this :

```
<?php
        $array = array(
            array(
                'id'       => 1,
                'name'      => 'Maths',
                'idParent' => 0
            ),
            array(
                'id'       => 2,
                'name'      => 'Topologie',
                'idParent' => 1
            ),
            array(
                'id'       => 3,
                'name'      => 'Algèbre',
                'idParent' => 1
            ),
            array(
                'id'       => 4,
                'name'      => 'Algèbre linéaire',
                'idParent' => 3
            ),
            array(
                'id'       => 5,
                'name'      => 'Arithmétique',
                'idParent' => 3
            ),
            array(
                'id'       => 6,
                'name'      => 'Thérorème de Bézout',
                'idParent' => 5
            ),
            array(
                'id'       => 7,
                'name'      => 'Informatique',
                'idParent' => 0
            ),
            array(
                'id'       => 8,
                'name'      => 'C-C++',
                'idParent' => 7
            ),
            array(
                'id'       => 9,
                'name'      => 'Les pointeurs',
                'idParent' => 8
            )
        );
         }
```

and the result is perfect :

```
 <ul>
        <li>Maths</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Topologie</li>
            <li>Algèbre</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Algèbre linéaire</li>
                <li>Arithmétique</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Thérorème de Bézout</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <li>Informatique</li>
        <ul>
            <li>C-C++</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Les pointeurs</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

but i need to translate this code from php to javascript ;

I tried a javascript code like this :

```
function makeArbo(array,currentParent,currLevel, prevLevel, result)
    {   
        if (typeof(currentParent)=='undefined'){

            currentParent=0 ;
            currLevel= 0 ;
            prevLevel=-1 ;
            result='';

    }
        if (array.length >0)
        {
          for (i=0;i< array.length;i++)
            {
                if (currentParent == array[i]['parentid'])
                {        
                   if (currLevel > prevLevel)
                        result += '<ul>';

                    if (currLevel == prevLevel)   
                        result += '</li>';

                    result += '<li>'+ array[i]['name']+'</li>';

                    if (currLevel > prevLevel)
                        prevLevel = currLevel;

                    currLevel++;
                    result+=makeArbo (array,array[i]['id'], currLevel, prevLevel, result.valueOf());

                    currLevel--;
                }  
           }
                  if  (currLevel == prevLevel) 
                  result += '</li></ul>';



         return result ;
        }

    }
}
```

The return isn't good, I don't have the same return like my first php code. I think that it is a problem crossing reference (by ref), because in my php code result is passed by reference "&$result = ''" .

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you think to use ajax, I mean to send your generated table from php?

Comment: Have you considered being a waiter instead on dumping a lot of code on a web site without a specific question?

Comment: Wouldn't it belong more to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) ? I'm not sure though, just a suggestion.

Comment: One could use templates (such as Mustache) that will work both in JavaScript and Php

Answer (score 0):

<del>I think your codes in js in not right because of the $array. As for js, when an array is transported, it only copies the address of the array, but not the whole status. For status, I mean the current position in the array, which is needed in your codes. So each time the function makeArbo is running in the js' part, the array is always beginning with the first element in its position, which is not what you have expected.</del>

<del>The solution is just moving the array outside of the function and let it to be a global variable, and everything will be OK.</del>

---------------------------------Just begin reading here-----------------------------------

1 [Javascript don't provide associative arrays](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/), you need to use an object instead. See

```
function myVar(id, name, idParent){
          this.id = id;
          this.name = name;
          this.idParent = idParent;
}
```

2 In Javascript, a variable without a var before itselt is a global variable. See

```
array = new Array(...
```

3 Replacing your other codes accordingly. The code below is tested in my own server as an html file.

4 Also, you should take care of the return value. Use an object to hold the return value or we can't get what we want. Finally everything works fine this time and I can go to my bed...

Cheers!!

My html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>

<p id="demo">My First Paragraph</p>

<script>

function myVar(id, name, idParent){
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.idParent = idParent;
}

array = new Array(
    new myVar(1, "maths", 0),
    new myVar(2, "Topologie", 1),
    new myVar(3, "Algèbre", 1),
    new myVar(4, "Algèbre linéaire", 3),
    new myVar(5, "Arithmétique", 3),
    new myVar(6, "Thérorème de Bézout", 5),
    new myVar(7, "Informatique", 0),
    new myVar(8, "C-C++", 7),
    new myVar(9, "Les pointeurs", 8)
);

function run() {
    var result = {};//the object to hold the values' position
    result.value = "";//the real values;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = makeArbo(0, 0, -1, result).value;
}


function makeArbo(currentParent , currLevel, prevLevel, result)
{
    if (array.length >0)
    {
       for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++)
       {
           if (currentParent == array[i].idParent)
           {        
               if (currLevel > prevLevel)
                   result.value += '<ul>';

               if (currLevel == prevLevel)   
                   result.value += '</li>';

               result.value += '<li>' + array[i].name + '</li>';

               if (currLevel > prevLevel)
                   prevLevel = currLevel;

               currLevel++;

               makeArbo(array[i].id, currLevel, prevLevel, result);

               currLevel--;
          }   
     }    
     if (currLevel == prevLevel) 
         result.value += '</li></ul>';

     return result;
}

}

window.onload = run;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes i used ajax for requesting my array and it  work fine.I was put a global variable for the return Json, but it show the same result, almost one quarter of the table.
I started full code for my question to be more explicit, it is not my intention to cram the screen code.

Comment: I copied the return Json table on a global variable with the slice method...and i used this global variable into my js code , but there is the same return ..

Comment: After you move the array as a global variable, you should remove that out you method's parameters either, did you do that? Your new function should be like this function makeArbo(currentParent,currLevel, prevLevel, result)